# proguard java optimizer external librarys classpath

Tags: java, proguard

I added two program jar files as input jar

1] entry.jar contains the main class of my java application created by using cmd jar cfm entry.jar Manifest.txt Mainclass.class (in manifest file -> Main-Class: Mainclass)

2] jar -cvf com.jar ./com (com package contains all other packages and class files)

and one jar file as out put file

3] out.jar

and library jars are

1] /opt/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/jre.jar
and all external jar files needed to run my application like mail.jar,lucene.jar,driver.jar etc

I processed in proguard and got out.jar file while running it using
java -jar out.jar am getting the main class and while going to other action like login getting exception like driver not found .

How can I add driver.jar class path and my package com's classpath

Comment: You might want to post *how exactly* you are calling ProGuard, i.e. post your code.

Comment: java -jar out.jar is the output jar of proguard while running using cmd java -jar out.jar getting esception Error while loading database driver..java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver